# Question regarding docs.oracle Class LinkedList<E>

Tags: java

```
java.util
Class LinkedList<E>

java.lang.Object
java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
java.util.AbstractList<E>
java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E>
java.util.LinkedList<E>
```

What are these classes?
and what are they telling me regarding linked list

```
java.lang.Object
java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
java.util.AbstractList<E>
java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E>
java.util.LinkedList<E>
```

Comment: It is the inheritance tree of `LinkedList`. Just like a `Dog` class extends from `Animal` and `Animal` extends maybe from `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet at the top from the [LinkedList javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> ```
> java.lang.Object
>     java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
>         java.util.AbstractList<E>
>             java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E>
>                 java.util.LinkedList<E>
> ```

shows you the inheritance tree of your class `LinkedList`. This class extends from the `AbstractSequentialList` class as shown in the javadoc page as well:

> ```
> public class LinkedList<E>
> extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
> implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
> ```

When you click on the link for the class `AbstractSequentialList` you will see the following class definition:

> ```
> public abstract class AbstractSequentialList<E>
> extends AbstractList<E>
> ```

And when you look at the inheritance tree of *that* class you will see:

> ```
> java.lang.Object
>     java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
>         java.util.AbstractList<E>
>             java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E>
> ```

As you see there is one entry less because you went "up once" to the base class of `LinkedList`, which is the `AbstractSequentialList` class.

This inheritance tree can be used to get an overview which class the class is extending from you are looking at and the class *that* class is extending from. This goes up until you reached the `Object` class, every class extends from (directly or indirectly). You can easily see which class the `LinkedList` class also "is" as well without clicking on each "extend" entry individual. This allows you to easily see, if you can write code like:

```
AbstractList<Integer> x = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

or

```
Object y = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

On the same note, on the javadoc page you sometimes see a list like:

> Direct Known Subclasses:
>
> ```
> (list of classes here)
> ```

This allows you to browse in the opposite direction to see which extends from that class you are looking at.

Also, you might want to look at the javadoc page at the top labeled "Tree" which shows the whole class hierarchy like the [Hierarchy For Package java.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html). You will see a similar inheritance tree and you can see information like:

*"The class `LinkedHashSet` is a `HashSet`, which is an `AbstractSet`, which is an `AbstractCollection`, which is an `Object`."*